# How to solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=kx+5,\ \frac{dy}{dt}=kx-ry$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $$\frac{dx}{dt}=kx+5$$$$\frac{dy}{dt}=kx-ry$$

I cannot solve it using matrix method, because there is a constant term in the first equation, can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to when the first equation is separable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $y' = \dfrac{dy}{dt} \to y'' = kx' - ry' = k(kx+5) - ry' \to y'' + ry' = k^2x + 5$. Put $v = y' \to v' + rv = k^2x+5$. From this you can continue as it is a popular 1st order DE.

As for the **matrix method**, rewrite the system as:

$\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} k & 0 \\ k & -r \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. From this you can continue with the matrix method.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

it is easier to make  a change of variable $$u = x  + \frac 5k, x = u - \frac5k, v = y + a, y = v - a $$ the differential equation for the new variables are 
$$\frac{du}{dx} = ku, \frac{dv}{dx} = k\left(u-\frac 5k\right) + r(v-a) = ku + rv-(5+ar), $$  if we choose $a = -\frac5r,$ then we have 
$$\frac{du}{dx} = ku, \frac{dv}{dx} = ku + rv. $$

now you don't have any constant terms.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much